# PIC18F4550 The blinking of my LED won't match the delay

Tags: microchip, pic18, xc8

I am using PICKit4 to program a PIC18F4550. I have plugged in a 40MHz Oscillator and here's my code including config bits. The LED stays ON for 12 seconds and off for 12 seconds instead of 5. What am I doing wrong? If I pick the wrong frequency for my oscillator and the wrong PLLDIV then I get the correct 5 second delay but that's not the correct way to fix this. I am using XC8 Compiler and
Here's the code:

```
#pragma config PLLDIV = 10      // PLL Prescaler Selection bits (Divide by 10 (40 MHz oscillator input))

#pragma config CPUDIV = OSC1_PLL2// System Clock Postscaler Selection bits ([Primary Oscillator Src: /1][96 MHz PLL Src: /2])
#pragma config USBDIV = 2       // USB Clock Selection bit (used in Full-Speed USB mode only; UCFG:FSEN = 1) (USB clock source comes from the 96 MHz PLL divided by 2)
#pragma config FOSC = HSPLL_HS  // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator, PLL enabled (HSPLL)) HSPLL_HS HSPLL_HS
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal/External Oscillator Switchover bit (Oscillator Switchover mode disabled)
#pragma config PWRT = OFF       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOR = OFF        // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset disabled in hardware and software)
#pragma config BORV = 3         // Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (Minimum setting 2.05V)
#pragma config VREGEN = OFF     // USB Voltage Regulator Enable bit (USB voltage regulator disabled)
#pragma config WDT = OFF        // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled (control is placed on the SWDTEN bit))
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768    // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)
#pragma config CCP2MX = ON      // CCP2 MUX bit (CCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RC1)
#pragma config PBADEN = OFF     // PORTB A/D Enable bit (PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as digital I/O on Reset)
#pragma config LPT1OSC = OFF    // Low-Power Timer 1 Oscillator Enable bit (Timer1 configured for higher power operation)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Enable bit (MCLR pin enabled; RE3 input pin disabled)
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will cause Reset)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Single-Supply ICSP Enable bit (Single-Supply ICSP enabled)
#pragma config ICPRT = OFF      // Dedicated In-Circuit Debug/Programming Port (ICPORT) Enable bit (ICPORT disabled)
#pragma config XINST = OFF      // Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Instruction set extension and Indexed Addressing mode disabled (Legacy mode))
#pragma config CP0 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP1 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP2 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP3 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CPB = OFF        // Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not code-protected)
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) are not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not write-protected)
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF      // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 40000000

void main(void) {
    
    TRISB = 0x00;
    
    while(1)
    {
        PORTBbits.RB0 = 1;
        __delay_ms(5000);
        PORTBbits.RB0 = 0;
        __delay_ms(5000);
    }  
       
    
    return;
}
```

Comment: The second line of config refers to a 96MHz oscillator, but you're using a 40MHz oscillator. The ratio of 96:40 is exactly the ratio of 12:5 you're seeing on your output. I don't know anything about the devices you're using, but that seems too much of a coincidence.

Comment: Hi, you defined the `_XTAL_FREQ` as 40.000.000 but what is your actual external crystal frequency that you apply to `OSC1` and `OSC2` pins? We need to know that since this device has frequency dividers as well as multipliers in order to graduate the input frequency.

Comment: Let me also know what capaitors do you use for the crystal osillator connection. You set the `USBDIV` config bit as well, do you use USB module in your project?